# How to view unreferenced citations

Tags: bibliographies, citing

Now I don't use BibTeX. Sometimes, when I revise the body of the article, I delete some citations to references. However, they still appear in the reference list, so they remain in the article. I would like a command that displays these references that are not cited in the main text, making it easier for me to remove them.

Below is a minimal example. We cite reference 2, but references 1 and 3 are not cited. I want to show their labels in a section called "Uncited References," showing these uncited references making it easier for me to remove them or cite them somewhere.

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

This is some text in the main body \cite{citation2}.

\section*{uncited references}
% References
\begin{thebibliography}{9}
\bibitem{citation1} Smith, J. (2020). Example reference 1.
\bibitem{citation2} Johnson, A. (2021). Example reference 2.
\bibitem{citation3} Williams, B. (2022). Example reference 3.
\end{thebibliography}

\end{document}
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Have a look at the `checkcites` tool: https://ctan.org/pkg/checkcites (don't get scared by how the site looks, that's just a special design for today)

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz  Thank you! I will see that. This website wishes a Happy Chinese New Year.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not directly a list, but you can use the backref package (with or without hyperref) to identify uncited citations. It will put links behind the cited references.

Be aware that you must put an empty line between each entry when you use it.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[backref=page]{hyperref}
\begin{document}

This is some text in the main body \cite{citation2}.

\section*{uncited references}
% References
\begin{thebibliography}{9}
\bibitem{citation1} Smith, J. (2020). Example reference 1.

\bibitem{citation2} Johnson, A. (2021). Example reference 2.

\bibitem{citation3} Williams, B. (2022). Example reference 3.
\end{thebibliography}

\end{document}
```

[image]